# TabControl в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как в `TabControl`-е правильно организовать работу вкладок и элементы внутри вкладок? Например 1 вкладка (`TabItem1`) работает с портом `RS232` и имеет свои элементы настроек, управления и свойства. 2 вкладка (`TabItem2`) работает с портом `USB` и имеет свои элементы настроек, управления и свойства. При добавлении вкладки выбираешь из списка с каким портом работать и соответственно должна добавиться вкладка и в этой вкладке должны быть те *элементы настроек*, *управления* и *свойства*, которые принадлежат выбранному порту. Вот ссылка на рисунок https://www.dropbox.com/s/2widu5i5uvqtrxv/TabControl.jpg

Comment: @MAKSIM, может это поможет: http://habrahabr.ru/post/111105/ Создайте для каждой вкладки свою модель представления, которую свяжете с соответствующим представлением (вкладкой).

Comment: @MAKSIM: Почитайте про MVVM. Никаких велосипедов не нужно, вся логика сводится к своевременному добавлению элемента в коллекцию ViewModel'ей, отвечающих за табы. (ViewModel — это и есть модель представления, упомянутая в комментарии @Pleshkov Ivan).

Answer (score 3):

Советую использовать MVVM-подход. Для этого вам нужно будет создать модели представления вкладок:

```
public abstract class TabVm : NotificationObject
{
    public string Header { get; }

    public TabVm(string header)
    {
        Header = header;
    }
}

public class Tab1Vm : TabVm
{
    public Tab1Vm()
        : base("Tab 1")
    {
    }
}

public class Tab2Vm : TabVm
{
    public Tab2Vm()
        : base("Tab 2")
    {
    }
}
```

NotificationObject - это класс, реализующий [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). TabVm - базовая модель представления для всех вкладок. Tab1Vm и Tab2Vm - конкретные вкладки.

Далее определяем модель представления, которая будет управлять вкладками:

```
public class MainVm : NotificationObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<TabVm> Tabs
    {
        get { return _tabs ?? (_tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabVm>()); }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<TabVm> _tabs;

    public TabVm SelectedTab
    {
        get { return _selectedTab; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedTab, value); }
    }
    private TabVm _selectedTab;

    public MainVm()
    {
        Tabs.Add(new Tab1Vm());
        Tabs.Add(new Tab2Vm());

        SelectedTab = Tabs.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Эта реализация ничем не управляет, а просто формирует перечень вкладок. Дале вы можете накрутить любую логику.

Ну и напоследок определяем представление:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainVm/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Tab1Vm}">
                <TextBlock Text="Tab 1 Content"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Tab2Vm}">
                <TextBlock Text="Tab 2 Content"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Я определил шаблоны вкладок прямо внутри окна. Вы можете вынести их в отдельные файлы, либо определить свой [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) и воспользоваться им.

Еще можете использовать [Ленту](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff799534(v=vs.110).aspx) вместо TabControl'a.