# Открытие форм в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть две формы. Необходимо открыть вторую, как бы внутри первой. На том же месте, не как модальное окно. По примерной аналогии с игрой: вы нажимаете кнопку "новая игра", меню должно скрыться и появится сама игра.

Пробовал код ниже, но окно открывается не на том же месте и следовательно выглядит как дичь.

```
this.Hide();
fg.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

Comment: Это называется не окно, а страница/вкладка/контрол. Окно в приложение это то, где есть крест закрытия (если грубо сказать..)..

Comment: Вам правильно подсказывают по поводу вкладок. Я предложу вам пару ссылок: [TabControl в WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/308855/189339) и [Класс TabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) и [Создание вкладок и TabControl](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/5.10.php)

Comment: ищите на тему страничная навигация

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634115/Как-в-wpf-менять-содержимое-окна/634211

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457703/wpf-mvvm-vs-Постраничная-навигация

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644129/wpf-mvvm-Замена-одного-представления-на-другое

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644580/Переключение-страниц-в-wpf-по-архитектуре-mvvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае будет правильно сделать наоборот: вызывать окно "Новая игра" из окна самой игры.

```
NewGameWindow form = new NewGameWindow();
form.Owner = this;
form.WindowStartupLocation = CenterOwner;
form.ShowDialog();
```

При этом можете скрывать, а можете не скрывать. Этот пример лучше подходит для небольших игрушек типа стандартного Сапера.

Если хочется, как в обычных играх: в одном окне - всё. То вместо фреймов проще использовать ContentControl. Просто присваиваете свойству Content нужный вам UserControl и у вас в том же окне поменяться содержимое.